# Run Python script in Theia of GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am very new to GCP (Google Cloud Platform). I got a Python script in VM and want to run it in the default editor, [Theia](https://theia-ide.org/), with its output comes inside a Theia widget.

Is it possible to do that or I must run from terminal?

Comment: I understand that the the GCP shell uses Theia, but it isn't particularly clear to me what you are asking unfortunately. Have you tried running your script in the GCP shell?

Answer (score 1):

Theia works by creating a server on the machine it runs on, and exposes a port for you to surf to the UI.

In order to connect to this port from your browser you will need to create an SSH tunnel from the machine your browser is running on to the VM in GCP. The most comfortable way I found to to that is to use gcloud on your local terminal:

```
export PROJECT_ID="my-project-id"
export ZONE="my-zone"
export INSTANCE_NAME="my-instance"
gcloud compute ssh --project $PROJECT_ID --zone $ZONE \
  $INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh